# RESTeasy and Returning to a JSP page with a model

Tags: model-view-controller, jboss, resteasy

Is there an easy, not using spring, way to have RESTeasy return a jsp or html page with a model? I want to do something similar to the spring ModelAndView where I have a request to say /contacts/loomer and have it return a mocked up object in a jsp template. All of the examples I see are for JSON/XML. I know in Jersey you can use the viewable, but I need to use only RESTeasy stuff.

Thanks!

I want something like this (but without the spring modelandview):

```
   @POST
   @PUT
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
   public ModelAndView saveContactForm(@Form Contact contact)
         throws URISyntaxException
   {
      service.save(contact);
      return viewAll();
   }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out for anyone who is interested. It was actually fairly trivial once I found an example.

```
@GET
@Path("{eventid}")
@Produces("text/html")
public void getEvent(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathParam("eventid") Long eventid) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

    EventDao eventdao = DaoFactory.getEventDao();
    Event event = eventdao.find(eventid);

    request.setAttribute("event", event);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("eventView.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a supported way of doing this or it is just a side effect of the implementation. I hope it's the former :-)

Comment: you may experience problems if you map your REST services to the root of your context "/*" (i.e. no "resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix") because RestEasy will try to handle also the request "eventView.jsp". As a workaround you can declare a servlet-mapping for each of your jsp :/

Answer (score 5):

Using `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-html` version `3.0.6.Final` you can directly access the `HttpServletRequest` and inject your own attributes before directing output to a RESTEasy `View`.

```
@GET
@Path("{eventid}")
@Produces("text/html")
public View getEvent(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                     @Context HttpServletRequest request,
                     @PathParam("eventid") Long eventid){

    EventDao eventdao = DaoFactory.getEventDao();
    Event event = eventdao.find(eventid);

    request.setAttribute("event", event);
    return new View("eventView.jsp");
}
```

This emulates some behavior of the `Htmleasy` plugin without having to rewire your `web.xml`.

Comment: What is the RESTeasy view object? I am having similar issues. I am surprised these parts of RESTEasy are so poorly documented.

Comment: `http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/javadocs/index.html`
To me it feels like RESTEasy prefers to return json or xml. Using it as an MVC returning jsp views is stretching the model. I bet that's why Htmleasy was written.

Answer (score 0):

I have voted up the above answer but it seems to work OK with RestEasy up to 2.3.2.Final, latest is 2.3.5.Final (for today). It seems to work OK with Jersey bundled with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 too.

This doesn't work with the RestEasy above 2.3.2.Final when I tried. I thought to share this observation as it took me a while to figure out what caused *'java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy262 cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest'*

However I am not trying to dive deep how to solve it, I came across some thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149950/1398360

Cheers