# How to redirect user when certain condition is met using REST JAX-RS implementation?

Tags: java, jsp, rest, redirect, jax-rs

I used to just use Tomcat and JSP pages which I can execute query, then assign query result into the array or object then pass that data onto client side via response.

```
request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "this is error!!");
request.getRequestDispatcher("report.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In client jsp code, I could do something like:

**${errorMessage}**

Then the "this is error!!" message would show up.

I want to do the same thing with REST JAX-RS GlassFish v3.

```
    @Path("schedule/test")
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Object tmpTest(String content) {
        try {

            //just my method to execute query and get result
            Vector out = (Vector)QueryManager.executeQuery;

            //if query result is empty, I want user to redirect to report.jsp page
            if(out.isEmpty()) {
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "This is error!!");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("report.jsp").forward(request, response);
                return null;
            }
        ....continue code......
   }
```

This results in mysterious exception I've never seen.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy109 cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getRequestFacade(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:1001)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
```

**So how can I redirect a user to report.jsp and also pass message like "This is error" ?**

The client jsp expects the error msg variable to have a value:

```
<b>${errorMessage}</b>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not RESTful. You need to throw a [`WebApplicationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) with a specific status code so that the client understands what exactly went wrong. E.g. when it's actually the server's mistake:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Or when it was after all client's mistake:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
```

See also [HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for an overview.

---

The `ClassCastException` which you're facing is by the way occurring because the dispatched `request` is actually not an instance of the servletcontainer-provided implementation (in this particular case, the one of Tomcat or a Tomcat-fork). After all, you shouldn't be doing it this way. You're developing a REST webservice, not a JSP/Servlet website. It are two distinct worlds.

Comment: I understand not to mix the JSP/Servlet and REST implementation, and throwing WebApplicationException but how can I pass some error message String as well??

Comment: Either create a [custom exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling) or just document the webservice properly under which conditions a specific response status code can occur.

Comment: Right, but how the client side code like Javascript (or JSP) can access the error message? I got:   throw new WebApplicationException(Response.ok("errorTest").build()); <br /><br /> I'm using regular POST method so this cause entire page to refresh to http 400.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it still doesn't answer the question.  Why is the ClassCastException occuring?  You say something about two different implementations of RequestDispatcher (?), but how do I identify the *correct* vendor implementation of the Dispatcher that I'm using (glassfish) ?

Comment: @Chris: it's a proxied request object. Say, it's not the same request instance as you'd get in a servlet `doGet()` method. It's a wrapper around it implementing the same `HttpServletRequest` interface, but it's not the container-specific instance itself. Read up the proxy pattern in wikipedia if you don't understand its uses.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, you should try WebApplicationException.
I believe you this would give you your desired answer:
Try this:

```
        if(out.isEmpty()) {
             java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("report.jsp");
             throw new WebApplicationException(Response.seeOther(location).build());
         }
```