# RestEasy open html/jsp page

Tags: rest, resteasy, webpage-rendering, requesthandler

There is a RestEasy method, which handles @GET requests. How is it possible to open a jsp/html page from that method?

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public void getMainPage(){
   //... 
}
```

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4110146/1407656)?

Comment: Which dependency should i add to maven project? Adding servlet-api 2.5 doesn't help...

Comment: I don't know, I don't even know what dependencies you have so far. It will be faster if you post a comment on the answer to that question, asking what dependencies are needed. When it comes to JAX-RS, I'm more of a Jersey person.

Answer (score 2):

**[HtmlEasy](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/)** is a great tool to render jsp files through RestEasy.

```
@Path("/")
public class Welcome {
    @GET @Path("/welcome/{name}")
    public View sayHi(@PathParm("name") String name) {
        return new View("/welcome.jsp", name);
    }
}
```

See [documents](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/UsingHtmleasy) for all options.

Answer (score 1):

Using [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-html version 3.0.6.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-html) you can directly access the HttpServletRequest and inject your own attributes before directing output to a RESTEasy View.

```
@GET
@Path("{eventid}")
@Produces("text/html")
public View getEvent(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                     @Context HttpServletRequest request,
                     @PathParam("eventid") Long eventid){

    EventDao eventdao = DaoFactory.getEventDao();
    Event event = eventdao.find(eventid);

    request.setAttribute("event", event);
    return new View("eventView.jsp");
}
```

This emulates some behavior of the Htmleasy plugin without having to rewire your web.xml.