# Is there an easy way to use JSP with RESTeasy?

Tags: java, jsp, resteasy

I developed a restful service to deliver xml and json using the **RESTeasy** framework.
Now I would like to develop a small web-frontent on top of that service but I wasn't able to find a way to use JSP-files in this framework directly without integrating Spring or another similar framework.

Is there an easy way to work with **JSP-files** (like rendering the jsp and delivering the resulting HTML to a web browser) in RESTeasy directly?

Maybe you know a tutorial which I couldn't find yet (every tutorial I could find so far is about json/xml or strings?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110146/resteasy-and-returning-to-a-jsp-page-with-a-model

Comment: I found this one too but I couldn't make it work so far.

Comment: May be you should ask a question about your particular problem with that link?