# How to access HTTP request's body with RESTEasy

Tags: java, http, rest, resteasy

I'm looking for a way to directly access the body of the HTTP request. In fact, in my code I receive different parameters in the body and I don't know in advance exactly what I will receive. Moreover I want to be as flexible as possible: I'm dealing with different requests that can vary and I want to handle them in a single method for each type of request (GET, POST, ... ).
Is there a way to handle this level of flexibility with RESTEasy? Should I switch to something else?

Comment: I tried using MessageBodyReaderInterceptor but I am not even sure that is made to do what I want. As far as I know, usually with RESTEasy you write methods that accept a POJO or several parameters, but I don't know them, so I cannot specify them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119495) you can access the HTTPServletRequest Object.

Once you have HTTPServletRequest object you should be able access the request body as usual. One example can be:

```
String requestBody = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw ex;
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
requestBody = stringBuilder.toString();
```