# How can I use RESTEasy to return to a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy in my project but I'm not that familiar with it. I need to use RESTEasy to return to a JSP page.

For example, I send a request to the server, the server processes the request then returns to a JSP page. How can I do this?

Comment: try with javax.ws.rs.core.Response this will help you to get a response for the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for RESTEasy that seems do do what you are asking: [HTMLEasy](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/). Slowly, there are features from it integrated into RESTEasy, mainly [the View component](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/FAQ#I%27ve_heard_that_Htmleasy_is_now_part_of_Resteasy?).

As an alternative I think you can also borrow some ideas form another JAX-RS implementation, like Jersey, who has a [Viewable](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/view/Viewable.html) class that can forward to a JSP based on a custom [MessageBodyWriter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) (see these classes for how it's implemented:[ViewableMessageBodyWriter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/1.14/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/template/ViewableMessageBodyWriter.java?av=f) and [JSPTemplateProcessor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.14/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JSPTemplateProcessor.java#JSPTemplateProcessor)).

And if the above looks a little bit heavy then have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110146/resteasy-and-returning-to-a-jsp-page-with-a-model) for a simple solution.